# What is this all about?

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

When debugging a asp.net web project from Visual Studio 2010, I notice in the solution explorer, there are such items as screenshot below. I don't know what they are and want to learn about them. All I can guess is that they are auto-generated client scripts created by IIS.

My question: What is the key words to google search for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Typically these are java script files emitted by ASP.Net to support, for example, ASP.Net AJAX. When you include an ASP.Net AJAX control on your page, the framework automatically serves this content too.

The axd extension is mapped the to the script resource handler.

Correction:

ScritptResource.axd serves script

WebResource.axd generally serves CSS (and possibly images compiled as embedded resources), I think, usually with e.g. AJAX / Third party compiled controls)

[image: See the Firebug response for one below]